# Insert missing rows in CSV of incrementally numbered files generated by directory listing?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have created a CSV from a set of files in a directory that are numbered incrementally:

`img1_1.jpg, img1_2.jpg ... img1_1999.jpg, img1_2000.jpg`

The CSV output is like so:

`filename, datetime`

eg:

```
img1_1.JPG,2011-05-11 09:16:33.000000000  
img1_3.jpg,2011-05-11 10:10:55.000000000  
img1_4.jpg,2011-05-11 10:17:31.000000000  
img1_6.jpg,2011-05-11 10:58:37.000000000
```

The problem is, there are a number of files missing in the listing, as some of the files don't exist. As a result, when imported, the actual row number does not match the file number.

Can anyone think of a reasonably efficient way to insert the missing rows so that the row number and filename matches up other than manually inserting rows for the missing ones? (There are over 800 missing rows).

**Background**

A previous programmer developed an uploader script and did not save the creation time of the mysql record in the database. I figured the easiest way to find the creation time for the majority of the records would be to output a directory listing of all the files and combine them in a spreadsheet.

Comment: In pure MySQL? This is ugly and probably requires a stored procedure. It's super easy with any scripting language, though.

Comment: I don't need to use MySQL, actually I'd prefer not to. I suppose I just need to write a script that parses the lines and compares the filename value, and if the next doesn't match, to insert a placeholder value. I suppose I could do this easily in say Ruby or python or something.

Answer (score 1):

You exactly need to do what you write in your comment to answer @tadman.
A text parser script to inject the missing lines with e.g. a date/time value that reflects the record is an empty one, i.e. there is no real data is behind it (e.g. date it to 1950-01-01 00:00:00). When it is done, bulk import the CSV.
I think this must be the best and most efficient solution.

Also, think about any future insert/delete/update events might occur to your data.
That would possibly break the chain you initially have had, so you might prefer instead, to introduce a numeric field for the jpegs IDs (and index that field), and leave the PK "as is" (auto increment).
In this case you can avoid CSV manipulation, as well as being chained to your AUTO PK (means: you will not get in trouble if a new jpeg arrives with an ID which was previously deleted, or existing ID, etc).
So the solution really depends on how you want to use this table in the future. If you give more details, I am sure the community can come up with even more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-time thing, it might be easiest to open up your csv in a spreadsheet.

If your table above is in sheet1, you could put something like the following in sheet2 (this is openoffice, but there are similar functions for Excel)

```
pre_filename | filename    | datetime
img1_1       | = A2&".JPG" | =OFFSET(Sheet1.$B$1;MATCH(B2;Sheet1.$A$2:$A$4;0);0)
```

You should be able to select the three cells above and drag them down to however many you need.